# .Net equivalent of JSP?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

What is the .Net equivalent of a JSP page?

Answer (score 10):

an ASPX page

(asp for ASP classic)

Code can be placed into an ASPX page which is then composed into magic that's rendered by the client.  There are also code files behind the ASPX pages which are .vb/.cs (Visual Basic and C# respectively) that pass data to the ASPX pages.

Really depends on what you're question is regarding for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is the closest thing is ASP.NET, the .NET replacement of the original ASP page. Do note that ASP.NET is not an exact replication of servlets though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478989.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are JSP and Servlet in J2EE world so to make one by one analogy with these, I would say

JSP <-> .aspx
Servlet <-> .cs